# Combobox ROWSOURCE from a veryhidden sheet

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a Combobox in a user form. I get the values for that Combobox from a specific column in my worksheet (Column T).

The Combobox is simply a list of insurance products and their pricing elements, it shows all products on the user form so that the user can select whatever products he wants.

The problem is that the list can grow or decrease (i.e. new products or deleting them). And to make things more complicated, the sheet that has the aforementioned values is located in a very hidden sheet (protected for confidentiality purposes). So whenever I open my userform, the Combobox doesn't show any data (i always have to open the hidden sheet so that they can be shown)

Here's the code

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Products = Range(Range("T7"), Range("T7").End(xlDown)).Address
      UserForm11.produit.RowSource = Products
    End Sub
```

Whenever i add the Worksheets name (Worksheets("Calcul").Range(Range("T7"), Range("T7").End(xlDown)).Address) it generates an error.

I just want the combo box to be dynamic and fixed to the source mentioned in the hidden sheet. Any clues?

Comment: Maybe try : `UserForm11.produit.RowSource = "'Calcul'!" & Products` ? Another way, set the Products as range ---> `with sheets("Calcul")` ... `set Products = .Range("T7", .Range("T7").End(xlDown))` ... `end with` ... `UserForm11.produit.List = application.transpose(Products)`. Btw, your `Products = Range(Range("T7"), Range("T7").End(xlDown)).Address` ---> the address will be the activesheet address. So I think you need to have : `with sheets("Calcul")` ... `Products = .Range("T7",.range("T7").End(xlDown)).Address` ... `end with`

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Products As Range
With Sheets("Calcul")
Products = .Range("T7", .Range("T7").End(xlDown)).Address
End With
UserForm11.produit.List = Application.Transpose(Products)
End Sub. Correct ?

Comment: could you please put it as code, cause I'm really lost and whenever I run it , it generates an error

Comment: if you want to use RowSource, dim Products as string. If you want to use .List, dim Products as range. Please have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
dim Products as string
with sheets("Calcul")
 Products = .Range("T7", .Range("T7").End(xlDown)).address
end with
      UserForm11.produit.RowSource = "'Calcul'!" & Products
End Sub
```

another way, Products as range.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
dim Products as range
with sheets("Calcul")
 Set Products = .Range("T7", .Range("T7").End(xlDown))
end with
      UserForm11.produit.list= application.transpose(Products)
End Sub
```

Comment: Bro you're a life saver. Thanks a lot . Sorry for my lack of understanding, i'm still new at this. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean : _"whenever I select another workbook"_. There are two opened workbook. Workbook-A and Workbook-B. The userform module which has that `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` is in Workbook-A.  From what workbook that you call to show the Userform ?

Answer (score 0):

The WorksheetFunction **OFFSET()** is made to create dynamic ranges. Creating a **Dynamic Named Range** in the Name Manager will allows us to see what range is being targeted. See: [Dynamic Named Range](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html).  The Named Range or its formula can be used as the ComboBox's Rowsource.  FYI: the Rowsource updates when the userform loads.  You'll have to clear the Rowsource  and reassign it to refresh the values after the userform is loaded.

> InsuranceProductsList =OFFSET(Calcul!$T$7,1,0,COUNTA(Calcul!$T:$T)-COUNTA(Calcul!$T$1:$T$7),1)

[image: Named Range Manager]